# serilog to log only debug, error and warning logs but not information

Tags: c#, serilog

I have an application with serilog configured for logging. I have a checkbox in my application, only on clicking that checkbox button it should log all information log else only Error and Warning log should be logged.

In debug mode how to log only Debug, error and warning log when the button is unchecked. I have been trying to do this since 2 days. I have tried all the ways suggested in google/stackoverflow using `.MinimumLevel.Debug()`/`restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug` it did not work for me. It logs Information log as well.

Please help me on this. To log only Debug,error and warning log.

`val` is true when checkbox enabled:

```
if (val == "true")
{
    _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                    .WriteTo.File(_filepath, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information)
                    .CreateLogger();
}
else if (val == "false")
{
    _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                    .WriteTo.File(_filepath, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug)
                    .CreateLogger();
}
```

when `val` is false, it.e., when check box is not enabled, it should log only debug,error and warning logs.

Comment: You won't achieve it using `MinimumLevel`, because Information has higher level than Debug, see [table with levels](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#minimum-level) (Verbose is min, Fatal is max)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot achieve it using `MinimumLevel`as @barbsan comment.

But you can use [filtering](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#filters) for in your case.

> Filters are just predicates over `LogEvent`

```
_logger  = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.File(_filepath)
    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(isNotInfoLevel)
    .CreateLogger();
```

And in below function you can add more conditions if needed

```
private static bool isNotInfoLevel(LogEvent le)
{
    return le.Level != LogEventLevel.Information;
}
```

Anther way by using `ByExcluding` to exclude information level

```
.Filter.ByExcluding((le) => le.Level == LogEventLevel.Information)
```